# Why does lsb_release -a list all those modules?

Tags: command-line

When I type `lsb_release -a` I get this:

[image]

I tried it a couple of days ago and I saw something more like this:

[image]

Why do I get all that?

Answer (score 2):

from lsb_release man page, it seems like that's the normal thing, look at the description for -v and -a, -v says `...The version is expressed as a colon separated list of LSB module descriptions.` that's what your seeing, a colon separated list of LSB modules

-a is `Display all of the above information.`, which includes -v

Answer (score 0):

Following up on geermc4's helpful answer, the difference may be from the installation of a package that happens to give you more support for Linux Standard Base.

lsb is one such package. My system has libnux-2.0-0 which supplies a few, but not as many as yours. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base and